# How to chose between two ui containers depending on data from API [React TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so I am working on a control panel that displays different videos / posts from an API source. I have a card div that displays video posts (Thumbnail + text) and then I have a second card div that displays more text-based posts.

The code for both of them is as follows:

```
  <div className="">
    <Link className="styledLink" to={`adminhelpcard/${this.state.id}`}>
      <div className="card">
        <h5 className="card-header">{this.state.title}</h5>

        <div>
          <img
            className="Sprite"
            onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
            onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
            src={this.state.thumbnail}
            style={
              this.state.tooManyRequests
                ? { display: "none" }
                : this.state.imageLoading
                ? { display: "null" }
                : { display: "null" }
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.tooManyRequests ? (
            <h6 className="mx-auto">
              <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2"></span>
            </h6>
          ) : null}
          <div className="card-body mx-auto">
            <h6 className="card-title">
              {this.state.title
                .toLowerCase()
                .split(" ")
                .map((letter) => letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1))
                .join(" ")}
            </h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
    <div className="horizontalCard">
      <div className="innerCard">
        <div className="leftImage">
          <img
            className="Sprite"
            onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
            onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
            src={this.state.thumbnail}
            style={
              this.state.tooManyRequests
                ? { display: "none" }
                : this.state.imageLoading
                ? { display: "null" }
                : { display: "null" }
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div className="rightText">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{this.state.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">...</p>
            <p className="card-text">...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The two containers look like so:
[image]

So my question is, how can I go about creating some sort of if-else statement that detects when a thumbnail link is provided by the api, and if it does, then it would provide a thumbnail container, whereas if it returned empty, then it would use a text-based container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by declaring this if else statement

```
render() {
    const isThumbnail = this.state.thumbnail;
    return (
      <div>
        {isThumbnail ? (
          <div className="horizontalCard">
            <div className="innerCard">
              <div className="leftImage">
                <img
                  className="Sprite"
                  onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                  onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                  src={this.state.thumbnail}
                  style={
                    this.state.tooManyRequests
                      ? { display: "none" }
                      : this.state.imageLoading
                      ? { display: "null" }
                      : { display: "null" }
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="rightText">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">{this.state.title}</h5>
                  <p className="card-text">...</p>
                  <p className="card-text">...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Link className="styledLink" to={`adminhelpcard/${this.state.id}`}>
            <div className="card">
              <h5 className="card-header">{this.state.title}</h5>

              <div>
                {this.state.tooManyRequests ? (
                  <h6 className="mx-auto">
                    <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2"></span>
                  </h6>
                ) : null}
                <div className="card-body mx-auto">
                  <h6 className="card-title">
                    {this.state.title
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .split(" ")
                      .map((letter) => letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1))
                      .join(" ")}
                  </h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion though, you can create a separate component for each "containers" that you have, so you could have shorter codes here and could be reusable if you needed to. :)

Comment: @threeFatCat How can I go about doing this?

Comment: you can check this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), which you will create a separate file for your codes for the container with img and you will name it as e.g. `<CardWithImg />` and `<CardNoImg /> ` for the other one, then just pass the data as a props. So your codes will be something like: `{isThumbnail ? <CardWithImg props /> : <CardNoImg  props /> }`